# v-bind href Retargeting to Localhost INSTEAD of Actual Link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The current button is binded to the data from v-for="book in books". The url in the database is equal to www.google.com.

```
<md-button  v-bind:href="book.url"  target="_blank">SEE ORIGINAL</md-button>
```

But when loading the page on localhost the button retargets to a new page but with the link "http://localhost:8080/www.google.com".

How do I get to be redirected only to "www.google.com" or how do I get it not to redirect with "http://localhost:8080/" in front ?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: what is md-button ? can you show your code please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the protocol to the start of it.

`http://www.google.com` will work, just `www.google.com` wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks!! That did it! Need higher reputation to upvote you! Will do soon! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Browsers make all href's relative unless they contain valid http. You can easily add in additional details into your link binding though:

```
:href=" 'http://'+ book.url"
```

Comment: The browser does that. Not Vue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @BillCriswell